# Word for "taking advantage of a second chance or opportunity"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Say a person doesn't act the first time around but gets a second chance and makes the right move. Is there any word that would describe such a situation or action?

Comment: This question could be improved if you provide more context (how do you hope to use the word? are you interested in phrases as well?) and tell us about the research you have done yourself to attempt to answer this question (for example, perhaps you have considered a phrase like *second time's the charm* but are looking for something else).

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you started.

Comment: thanks all for the help. i'll do my best to put this into context, a sort of real life scenario. say a person sees someone and wants to say something but doesnt. what if that that person was provided another opportunity, get another shot. does a word exist that implies "second chance"...another opportunity to take the initiative..i dont know exactly what i am looking for but just something that describes that scenario. the antonym of Mamihlapinatapai. perhaps i should make it it's own question

Answer (score 2):

How about "He redeemed himself"?

Answer (score 0):

*Didn't repeat his mistake*, *seized the opportunity*, *didn't squander/miss the opportunity*. 
I agree, some context would help.

Comment: I like the word "squander". Two syllables, flows of the toungue.. Is there any word that you could think of that reads similiarly but means the exact opposite of squander. Not a phrase like "didn't squander" but actually a word that means exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

The word I would use to describe the person is **retriever**.